# RoR - How to add icons in a dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to bind Categories drop down on Posts search page. The drop down should display Category image as icon on left side of category name in the dropdown.

Following line binds ALL Categories and shows their names in dropdown:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:cat_id_eq, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, :include_blank => 'Any') %>
```

How can I show their images in dropdown, with their names ?

*NOTE: Post belongs_to Category and Category has_many Posts.*

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As i know you can't put image in a normal dropdown list. You either have to use a plugin or make your own div with child that has image and text and manage your own event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to put images into an option in a [select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). You would need to make a custom select list for that. The jQuery plugin [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2) has a [templating feature](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#templating), among others.